add-apt-repository CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED
I run WSL (ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS) and want to use add-apt-repository but we have TLS interception in-place.
Error message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 364, in <module>
    sys.exit(0 if addaptrepo.main() else 1)
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 347, in main
    shortcut = handler(source, **shortcut_params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/shortcuts.py", line 40, in shortcut_handler
    return handler(shortcut, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 82, in __init__
    if self.lpppa.publish_debug_symbols:
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 120, in lpppa
    self._lpppa = self.lpteam.getPPAByName(name=self.ppaname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 107, in lpteam
    self._lpteam = self.lp.people(self.teamname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 98, in lp
    self._lp = login_func("%s.%s" % (self.__module__, self.__class__.__name__),
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/launchpadlib/launchpad.py", line 494, in login_anonymously
    return cls(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/launchpadlib/launchpad.py", line 230, in __init__
    super(Launchpad, self).__init__(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/resource.py", line 472, in __init__
    self._wadl = self._browser.get_wadl_application(self._root_uri)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/_browser.py", line 447, in get_wadl_application
    response, content = self._request(url, media_type=wadl_type)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/_browser.py", line 389, in _request
    response, content = self._request_and_retry(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/_browser.py", line 359, in _request_and_retry
    response, content = self._connection.request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1725, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/launchpadlib/launchpad.py", line 144, in _request
    response, content = super(LaunchpadOAuthAwareHttp, self)._request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/_browser.py", line 184, in _request
    return super(RestfulHttp, self)._request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1441, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1363, in _conn_request
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1155, in connect
    self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=self.host)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 513, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 1100, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 1371, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1007)

What I already tried:
Add certificates to the system store
I downloaded the complete chain of the certificates and added the certificates below: /usr/share/ca-certificates/.
After that, I edited the /etc/ca-certificates.conf and added the lines:
cert1.crt
cert2.crt
cert3.crt

(Yes, there are a root certificate, a intermediate, another intermediate - so If I call a website via browser my cert chain would be: root -> intermediate1 -> intermediate2 -> leaf)
after that I run sudo update-ca-certificates and 3 certifcates got added.
Because I read it sometimes, I also run sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates to verify that these new certificates are selected.
If I run add-apt-repository again -> same error.
HTTPLIB2_CA_CERTS
Because the error message shows that http2lib is involved, I found that there is a environment variable HTTPLIB2_CA_CERTS that can be used. reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18557744/how-to-update-cacerts-txt-of-httplib2-for-github/73506551#73506551
I tried this method and set the variable to the location of all these certificates -> same error message.
/etc/ssl/certs
I also tried to put the certs directly in the folder /etc/ssl/certs and run sudo update-ca-certificates -> also not working.
REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE
Another thing I tried is to use the REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE - but that also leads to error. Other tools use the REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE and it works fine - so I guess no issue on setting the variable correctly.
Can someone help me to solve the issue and get it running? (I know there are workarounds to add the repository the old fashioned way and with http:// - but I want to use add-apt-repository)

According to the source, httplib2 doesn't use the system cert store so any changes you make there are useless. It uses HTTPLIB2_CA_CERTS if set, else modules ca_certs_locator or certifi if present (I've never seen the former anywhere), else a hardcoded list.
Thus HTTPLIB2_CA_CERTS should work, but I am concerned by your description of it as a 'location'. Does that mean a directory? It cannot be a directory; it must be a file, specifically a 'bundle' file that contains one or more certs in PEM format. But that should have given a quite different error, and you say it didn't. If a file, are its contents in PEM format?
REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE is clearly out; it only applies to things that use requests, and this doesn't.

Hi, ah good to know.
Yeah - I put the combined .pem file into the directory: /usr/share/ca-certificates/.
After that I did:
export HTTPLIB2_CA_CERTS=/usr/share/ca-certificates/cert_chain.pem (I also tried the file extension .crt) and after that I used:
sudo  -E add-apt-repository XYZ. Same error message. I guess the -E parameter is needed, so that my new environment variable is also available from the sudo context.

Enki: you didn't mention sudo, although given Ubuntu I probably should have guessed it. Yes that interferes with envvars and -E may fix it but maybe not depending on the state of your system. Try sudo -E printenv HTTPLIB2_CA_CERTS to check.

Yes, that seems to work fine:
sudo -E printenv HTTPLIB2_CA_CERTS Output:
/usr/share/ca-certificates/cert_chain.pem

Oh, the error message changed to: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: authority and subject key identifier mismatch.  The certificate files is the same as before.

Then it is (now) using your file as directed, but there's something wrong with at least one of the certificates in your file -- or received from the faked server. If you have openssl, do openssl s_client -connect $host:$port -CAfile /yourCAcertfile -no-CApath; that should do the same verification as nodejs/httplib2 (and get the same error) but show more details about it.

Actually, there was an issue with my certificate.I fixed that.

export HTTPLIB2_CA_CERTS=/usr/share/ca-certificates/cert_chain.pem
openssl s_client -connect google.de:443 -CAfile /usr/share/ca-certificates/cert_chain.pem -no-CApath -> result: SSL handshake has read 4691 bytes and written 404 bytes
Verification: OK
sudo -E printenv HTTPLIB2_CA_CERTS -> shows: /usr/share/ca-certificates/cert_chain.pem
sudo -E add-apt-repository ppa:XX -> same issue (authority and subject key identifier mismatch)

